# Remapping "browser home" media key when browser is focused

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, windows-registry

I have remapped the "browser home" media key on my keyboard through the registry in order to have it run a script rather than open the browser.  This generally works fine except when a browser is focused it navigates to its configured home page rather than calling my script.  Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer all prevent my script from being run when they are focused which makes me think (hope) it's more of a system level issue that can be resolved through a registry setting rather than a hard coded application specific thing.

To make the "browser home" key call my script I modified the following registry key to include `ShellExecute`:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\7`

(See [here](http://ashish.vashisht.net/2008/01/configuring-keyboard-multimedia-keys.html) for more information about updating the registry to remap the media keys.)

Is there a way I can make it so that my remapped "browser home" key calls my script regardless of which application currently has focus?